# Deduction guides, initializer_list, and the type deduction process

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, initializer-list, list-initialization

Consider the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LVzviEa858h3Q86b):

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
struct test
{
    test(const std::pair<T, T> &)
    {}
};

template<class T>
test(std::initializer_list<T>) -> test<T>;

int main()
{
    test t{{1, 2}};
}
```

I would like to understand why this trick with `initializer_list` compiles. It looks like at first, {1, 2} is treated as an `initializer_list`, but then it's *re-interpreted* as a list-initialization of `pair`.

What exactly happens here, step-by-step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles because that's how class template deduction guides work.

Deduction guides are *hypothetical* constructors of the type. They don't really exist. Their only purpose is to determine how to deduce class template parameters.

Once the deduction is made, the actual C++ code takes over with a specific instantion of `test`. So instead of `test t{{1, 2}};`, the compiler behaves as if you had said `test<int> t{{1, 2}};`.

`test<int>` has a constructor that takes a `pair<int, int>`, which can match the values in the braced-init-list, so that's what gets called.

This kind of thing was done in part to allow aggregates to participate in class template argument deduction. Aggregates don't have user-provided constructors, so if deduction guides were limited to just real constructors, you couldn't have aggregates work.

So we get to have this class template deduction guide for `std::array`:

```
template <class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

This allows `std::array arr = {2, 4, 6, 7};` to work. It deduces both the template argument and the length from the guide, but since the guide is not a constructor, `array` gets to remain an aggregate.

Comment: I understand that the guide is a "hypothetical" constructor. What confused me was the fact that the {1, 2} construct was treated differently at the different stages of this process...

Answer (score 1):

With your deduction guide we end up with what is equivalent to:

```
test<int> t{{1, 2}};
```

This works due to list initialization, section [dcl.init.listp3.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.7) which says:

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The
>   applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a
>   narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the
>   arguments, the program is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   S(std::initializer_list<double>); // #1
>   S(std::initializer_list<int>);    // #2
>   S();                              // #3
>   // ...
> };
> S s1 = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };           // invoke #1
> S s2 = { 1, 2, 3 };                 // invoke #2
> S s3 = { };                         // invoke #3
> ```
>
> — end example  ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct Map {
>   Map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string,int>>);
> };
> Map ship = {{"Sophie",14}, {"Surprise",28}};
> ```
>
> — end example  ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   // no initializer-list constructors
>   S(int, double, double);           // #1
>   S();                              // #2
>   // ...
> };
> S s1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 };               // OK: invoke #1
> S s2 { 1.0, 2, 3 };                 // error: narrowing
> S s3 { };                           // OK: invoke #2
> ```
>
> — end example  ]

Otherwise we have a [non-deduced context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.6)